# Mongoose populate and sort by length struggle

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following mongoose schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  fragments: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Fragment'}]
}, { timestamps: true, collection: 'user' });
```

And

```
const fragmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
}, { timestamps: true, collection: 'fragment' });
```

In the data, I have a reference in the `Fragment`, but not in the `User`:

User:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58373e571cbccb010012bfcd"),
    "email" : "email@example.com",
    // no "fragments": [ObjectId('58075ce37b7f2f01002b718f')] etc.
}
```

Fragment:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58075ce37b7f2f01002b718f"),
    "text" : "Donc, il faut changer de méthode",
    "owner" : ObjectId("58075ce27b7f2f01002b717f")
}
```

I would like to query users sorted by the count of number of fragments, and I can't achieve this ...

First, I'd like to make this work:

```
User.find({_id: '58075ce27b7f2f01002b717f'})
  .populate('fragments').exec(console.log)
```

returns

```
{ 
  _id: 58075ce27b7f2f01002b717f,
  email: 'bububg@hotmail.fr',
  fragments: []
}
```

while I should have at least the above `fragment` included.

And regarding the sorted query, here's where I am now:

```
User.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "email": 1,
    "fragments": 1,
    "nbFragments": { "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$fragments", [] ] } }
  }},
  { "$sort": { "nbFragments": -1 } }
], console.log)
```

At least it runs, but all the `nbFragments` fields are set to 0. This might be related to the fact that `.populate('fragments')` doesn't work but I can't be sure.

Thanks for the help, I did not expect so much trouble using Mongodb...

---

EDIT: thanks @Veeram, unfortunately your solution is not working:

```
User.find({}).find({_id: '58075ce27b7f2f01002b717f'}).populate('fragments').exec(console.log)
[ { _id: 58075ce27b7f2f01002b717f,
    email: 'email@example.com',
    // no fragments entry
} ]
```

while I updated my schema:

```
userSchema.virtual('fragments', {
  ref: 'Fragment',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'owner',
  options: { sort: { number: 1 }}, // Added sort just as an example
});
```

And regarding the aggregate, with:

```
User.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'Fragment',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'owner',
    as: 'fragments'
  }
}, { "$project": {
  "email": 1,
  "fragments": 1,
  "nbFragments": {
    "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$fragments", [] ] } }
}}, { "$sort": { "nbFragments": -1 } }
]).exec(console.log)
```

I get:

```
{ 
  _id: 58075ce27b7f2f01002b717f,
  email: 'email@example.com',
  fragments: [] // fragments are always empty while they shouldn't!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with following data

```
User:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58373e571cbccb010012bfcd"),
    "email" : "email@example.com"
}

Fragment:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58075ce37b7f2f01002b718f"),
    "text" : "Donc, il faut changer de méthode",
    "owner" : ObjectId("58373e571cbccb010012bfcd")
}
```

Response

```
[{"_id":"58373e571cbccb010012bfcd","email":"email@example.com","fragments":[{"_id":"58075ce37b7f2f01002b718f","text":"Donc, il faut changer de méthode","owner":"58373e571cbccb010012bfcd"}],"nbFragments":1}]
```

You define schema to use `owner` to populate the `fragments` also called virtual population. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

```
const userSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
      email: { type: String, unique: true }
    }, { timestamps: true, collection: 'user' });

var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

const fragmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
}, { timestamps: true, collection: 'fragment' });

var Fragment = mongoose.model("Fragment", fragmentSchema);

userSchema.virtual('fragments', {
    ref: 'Fragment',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'owner',
    options: { sort: { text: -1 }}, // Added sort just as an example
});
```

This will now work as expected, but I don't know a way to sort on some dynamic field like count of number of fragments in mongoose. I don't think it is possible

```
User.find({_id: '58373e571cbccb010012bfcd'})
      .populate('fragments').exec(function (err, user) {
           console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
      });
```

Okay now for dynamic sorting, you have to use alternative raw mongo query with a `$lookup` (equivalent of `populate`).

```
const userSchema =  new mongoose.Schema({
      email: { type: String, unique: true }
    }, { timestamps: true, collection: 'user' });

var User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

const fragmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: String,
  owner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
}, { timestamps: true, collection: 'fragment' });

User.aggregate([{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'fragment',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'owner',
    as: 'fragments'
  }
}, { "$project": {
  "email": 1,
  "fragments": 1,
  "nbFragments": {
    "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$fragments", [] ] } }
}}, { "$sort": { "nbFragments": -1 } }
]).exec(function (err, user) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Veeram. I edited my question with the intermediate results. Still not working :( I'm considering adding the double reference in the User document, using push/pull callbacks, it would make sense, wouldn't it?

Comment: Your are welcome. Virtual populate is only available from 4.5 version mongoose. Tested both the variants with 4.8.6 and updated with the latest code. For the aggregate function the collection name in the `from` field in the `$lookup` should be fragment lower case f. That should work.

Comment: I'm using 4.6 so it should work. But anyway, since ordering is not possible and the *expected behavior* seems to be having the keys stored in the document, I'll go for this solution and try to figure out how to make it work! Mongodb is hard though

Comment: I have given you the entire code which has worked for me and tested too. You will have to use `$lookup` variant for ordering no matter which version of mongoose you are on.